# JavaScript using variables outside of function events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am pretty new to java-script. So sorry if this is a stupid question.

I have the JavaScript function for some accordion elements, The function it is work without any problem. But I want when I click on any accordion element get the `id` attribute of that accordion (As you see in click function event), then put this `id` before the `contentTypeValue` selector in the second function.

The `showHideUniMul` function doesn't work, I think this is due to the `itemId` variable. How can use the `itemId` outside the click event function until work with `showHideUniMul` function?

**Info** the `showHideUniMul` function work without any problem when I don't use `itemId` variable and the `itemId` return to the `id` attribute successfully.

```
$('ul#menu-to-edit li a.item-edit').click(function() {
    var itemId = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
});

var showHideUniMul = function() {
    var contentTypeValue = $(itemId + ' .field-content-type input:checked').val();
    if (contentTypeValue === 'uniform') {
       //some codes here
    } else if (contentTypeValue === 'multiple') {
       //some codes here
    } else {
       //some codes here
    }
};

showHideUniMul();
contentType.on('change', showHideUniMul);
```

**EDIT**

This is my Html structure

```
    <ul id="menu-to-edit">
    <li id="1">
        <div>
            <div>
                <span>
                    <a class="item-edit">Click Me and then check radio boxes</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="field-content-type">
                <input type="radio" name="uniform[1]" value="uniform" />
                <input type="radio" name="multiple[1]" value="multiple" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="2">
        <div>
            <div>
                <span>
                    <a class="item-edit">Click Me and then check radio boxes</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="field-content-type">
                <input type="radio" name="uniform[2]" value="uniform" />
                <input type="radio" name="multiple[2]" value="multiple" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: well  you can not use a variable when it is defined in a different scope. So in order to do it, you need to define the variable in a scope where both can see it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: How is the click event related to that function?  Did you mean to call that function in the click event?

Comment: @David I want to call the `showHideUniMul` according to the `id` attribute

Comment: @ScottMarcus I say the functions work without any problem but I want the way or method of using `itemId` with the `showHideUniMul` function

Comment: @SAFEEN1990: But *when* do you want to call the function?  The id only exists in the context of the click event, and you're not calling the function from the click event.

Comment: @David in the click event function only I want to get the id attribute then using this id as a selector with the `contentTypeValue` variable.

Comment: @SAFEEN1990: Then the answers below should do the trick.

Comment: The first time the showHideUniMul runs, the itemId will not exist as nothing would have invoked that click method yet.  And nothing in that showHideUniMul is checking to see if the itemId is set or not.  This is regardless of if you fix your scoping issue with the itemId being scoped down to the click method.  EDIT: and the use of repeated `parent()` calls is overly tightly coupled the logic to the markup.  A more lose coupling would involve the use of `closest(parentSelector)`

Comment: I understand, but the best way to post questions is such that we can actually run the code you are posting and then provide a working version. Questions should always be complete.

Comment: @Taplar as I say I'm new in javascript I added some changes to my WordPress menu items I need this jquery trick please help me and correct my code or add the fresh working code for me

Comment: Quite a few people here and in the answers have addressed the scope issue, yet you seem to be ignoring their feedback.  Then in your change handler you just need to make sure it isn't null or undefined.

Comment: @SAFEEN1990  check the answer below and if useful then only mark the answer as accepted.Thanks

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thanks for reply my question now I edit the question and I add my HTML structure if you can I want you to add change event to my radio check boxes instead of the click event over the normal button

Comment: @SAFEEN1990  `var contentTypeValue = $(itemId + ' .field-content-type input:checked').val();` this code will be something like `1+"uniform"` which have no useful meanings

Comment: @AlivetoDie you right, I want `contentTypeValue ` like this contentTypeValue  = The checked radio button in menu item that has the id 1 or 2 to according to click event

Comment: @SAFEEN1990  your radio button don't have id's

Comment: @AlivetoDie the radio buttons have the name attributes if you need the name instead of id you can use the name attributes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150996/discussion-between-safeen-1990-and-alive-to-die).

Comment: @AlivetoDie thanks it is work now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Note:-*** variable created inside a function vanishes after function execution completed(***due to local scope***), so you can't use them into other function directly.

You need to use ***global-variable*** scope/concept here:-

```
var itemId; // define global

$('ul#menu-to-edit li a.item-edit').click(function() {
    itemId = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
});

var showHideUniMul = function() {
    var contentTypeValue = $(itemId + ' .field-content-type input:checked').val();
    if (contentTypeValue === 'uniform') {
       //some codes here
    } else if (contentTypeValue === 'multiple') {
       //some codes here
    } else {
       //some codes here
    }
};

showHideUniMul();
contentType.on('change', showHideUniMul);
```

***A sample example:-***

```js
var itemId; // define global

$('ul#menu-to-edit li a.item-edit').click(function() {
  itemId = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
});

var showHideUniMul = function() {
  var contentTypeValue = $('.field-content-type input:checked').val();
  console.log(itemId);
 
};
$('input[type=radio]').on('change',function(){
  showHideUniMul();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-to-edit">
  <li id="1">
    <div>
      <div>
      <span>
        <a class="item-edit">Click Me and then check radio boxes</a>
      </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="field-content-type">
        <input type="radio" name="uniform[1]" value="uniform" />
        <input type="radio" name="multiple[1]" value="multiple" />
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li id="2">
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>
          <a class="item-edit">Click Me and then check radio boxes</a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="field-content-type">
        <input type="radio" name="uniform[2]" value="uniform" />
        <input type="radio" name="multiple[2]" value="multiple" />
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I was looking at this and thinking, aside from the scope issue.  It kind of would make sense to store the element rather than the id.  Then you wouldn't need that extra lookup.  You could just find() off of it.

Comment: @Taplar  yes that will be a better option but  it definitely depend upon what structure and what depth-level of code used there.

Comment: @AlivetoDie thank you brother now it works perfectly

Comment: @SAFEEN1990  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because of your scoping - itemId is not defined in the showHideUniMul() function. Change your code to the following -

```
var itemId;

$('ul#menu-to-edit li a.item-edit').click(function() {
    itemId = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
});

var showHideUniMul = function() {
    var contentTypeValue = $('#' + itemId + ' .field-content-type input:checked').val();
    if (contentTypeValue === 'uniform') {
       //some codes here
    } else if (contentTypeValue === 'multiple') {
       //some codes here
    } else {
       //some codes here
    }
};

showHideUniMul();
contentType.on('change', showHideUniMul);
```

This makes itemId global and available for access from any function. You will also need to add '#' + itemId to the value of contentTypeValue

Comment: why is this getting downvoted - this is the right answer assuming you get itemId properly on click